# Using 'printf' on a variable in C

Tags: c, variables

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int x = 1;

    printf("please make a selection with your keyboard\n");
    sleep(1);
    printf("1.\n");

    char input;
    scanf("%c", &input);
    switch (input) {
        case '1':
            x = x + 1;
            printf(x);
    }
    return(0);
}
```

I am trying a make a variable add to itself and then print that variable out, but I can't seem to get my code to work.

My output error is

```
newcode1.c: In function ‘main’:
newcode1.c:20:2: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘printf’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
In file included from newcode1.c:1:0:
/usr/include/stdio.h:362:12: note: expected ‘const char * __restrict__’ but argument is of type ‘int’
newcode1.c:20:2: warning: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Wformat-security]
```

Comment: BTW, you are not printing a variable, you are printing the [current] *value* of some variable.

Comment: Also, it is better to initialize `input` before the `scanf` and to test the result of `scanf`

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Your `printf` needs a format string:

```
printf("%d\n", x);
```

This [reference page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) gives details on how to use `printf` and related functions.

Comment: That's all I needed to do?!?!?! Thanks it worked.

Answer (score 2):

As [Shafik already wrote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16675287/using-printf-on-a-variable-in-c/16675310#16675310), you need to use the right format because `scanf` gets you a char.

Don't hesitate to look at *[printf - C++ Reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/)* if you aren't sure about the usage.

Hint: It's faster/nicer to write `x = x + 1`; the shorter way is: `x++;`